# 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'MultipartFile' - intellij message

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

When I build a spring project I can't create this model.
How can I fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity can not store MultipartFile you can use byte[] and @Lob annotation to store it to database.

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "photo", columnDefinition="BLOB")
private byte[] photo;
```